# How to write a query of 3 tables same columns and among them one different column to execute

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables,among them there are 3 same column names to 3 tables
but the 3rd table has 3rd column is different to first second table columns..
My need will clarify given image and query...  [image]

```
//this the query I'm using but not I wanted
select l.admission_number,l.student_class ,l.student_name ,l.telugu  from lkg_to_seventh_marks as l 
union all 
select e.admission_number ,e.student_class ,e.student_name ,e.telugu  from eighth_to_ninth_marks as e 
union all
select t.admission_number ,t.student_class ,t.student_name,t.telugu_1  from tenthclass_marks as t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
select l.admission_number,l.student_class ,l.student_name,l.telugu,NULL as telugu_1 
from lkg_to_seventh_marks as l 
union all 
select e.admission_number ,e.student_class ,e.student_name ,e.telugu ,NULL  as telungu_1
from eighth_to_ninth_marks as e 
union all
select t.admission_number ,t.student_class ,t.student_name,NULL as telugu, t.telugu_1 
from tenthclass_marks as t
```

I Think do you want this query

```
select l.admission_number,l.student_class ,l.student_name,cast(l.telugu as char(50))
,'NULL' as telugu_1  from lkg_to_seventh_marks as l 
union all 
select e.admission_number ,e.student_class ,e.student_name ,cast(e.telugu as char(50))
,'NULL'as telungu_1
from eighth_to_ninth_marks as e 
union all
select t.admission_number ,t.student_class ,t.student_name,'NULL'as telugu, 
cast(t.telugu_1 as char(50)) as telungu_1
rom tenthclass_marks as t
```

Comment: instead of 0 value in empty cell can we get a null string

Comment: can we get a NULL text instead of 0 value in empty cell??
please add a query if u get an idea

Comment: @ShivaDebrown its ok for you or you want change anything?

Comment: yeah..
I just want that to place a text as NULL where ever 0 is

Comment: If I use same query to load the data to datagridview the datagridview cells are not visible with NULL text,cells are with just empty..

Comment: do you want to show with null or empty @ShivaDebrown

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful.

```
select l.admission_number,l.student_class ,l.student_name,l.telugu,null as telugu_1 from lkg_to_seventh_marks as l union all select e.admission_number ,e.student_class ,e.student_name ,e.telugu ,null as telungu_1 from eighth_to_ninth_marks as e union all select t.admission_number ,t.student_class ,t.student_name,0 as telugu, t.telugu_1 from tenthclass_marks as t
```

Comment: I want NULL text in datagridview cells if I use same query to load the data to datagridview

Comment: this query give null value for first two table.

Comment: If I load same query to datagridview then the datagridview cells will be showing empty cell not with filled NULL text..

Comment: for that change NULL to '' (empty quotes).

Comment: Empty Quotes give 0 value