# How to set some text to datagridview cell when its cell contains 0 value in c#?

Tags: c#, replace, datagridview, null, cell

I have a datagridview and its data from sql database.

My datagridview some cells filled with 0(zero) value.
I want to set a NULL text at where the 0 value is filled in the datagridview.

[image]

```
//I'm using this code but not working
 private void dataGridView4_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 7; j < dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) == 0)
                {
                    dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = "Null";
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

My SQL Query is  :

`select l.admission_number,l.student_class ,l.student_name,hindi,maths,social,l.telugu,l.english ,
'' as english_1,'' as english_2,l.science, '' as ns,'' as ps  from lkg_to_seventh_marks as l union all select e.admission_number ,e.student_class ,
e.student_name ,hindi,maths,social,e.telugu,'' as english,e.english_1 ,e.english_2,'' as science,e.ns,e.ps from eighth_to_ninth_marks as e`

Comment: I am thinking you can't manually manipulate the fields because you are databinding.

Comment: by what means are you obtaining the "DATA" i.e. dataset/SQLserver , EF/MySQL , EF/SQLserver ??????

Comment: yeah.. of course I'm binding the data,But I want to set some text at 0 values.. If any possibility tell me plz.Here I'm binding data from Microsoft SQL server

Comment: very possible and Please tell me how you get the data. what is your SQL Query? is it auto generated by VS IDE? is this winforms or WPF. I am trying to say what is your context and how much control/access do you have to the data? what are you using to bind the data?

Comment: Why don't you return the desired data directly from data source? I mean replace any 0 values with 'NULL' in your SQL query.

Comment: @Alireza thanks for hitting on my point so pointedly

Comment: @RadioSpace And you did it in detail

Comment: I am not able to write a query which i wanted exactly will u please modify it if it is possible please @Alireza

Comment: Which one of your fields should return a NULL instead of 0? All of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835365/alireza) said I am replacing any 0 values with 'NULL' in my SQL query with casting.for 3 tables having some different columns and some same columns

```css
select l.admission_number,l.student_class ,l.student_name,cast(l.telugu as char(4)) as telugu,
'NULL' as telugu_1,'NULL' as telugu_2,l.hindi,cast(l.english as CHAR(4)) as english,'NULL' as english_1,'NULL' as english_2,
cast(l.maths as CHAR(4)) as maths,'NULL' as maths_1,'NULL' as maths_2,
cast(l.science as CHAR(4)) as science,'NULL' as ns,'NULL' as ps,
cast(l.social as CHAR(4)) as social,'NULL' as social_1,
'NULL' as social_2,l.total
from lkg_to_seventh_marks as l 

union all 

select e.admission_number ,e.student_class ,e.student_name ,
cast(e.telugu as char(4)) as telugu,'NULL'as telugu_1,'NULL' as telugu_2,e.hindi,
'NULL' as english,cast(e.english_1 as CHAR(4)) as english_1,
CAST(e.english_2 as CHAR(4)) as english_2,CAST(e.maths as CHAR(4)) as maths,'NULL' as maths_1,
'NULL' as maths_2,'NULL' as science,cast(e.ns as CHAR(4)) as ns,CAST(e.ps as CHAR(4)) as ps,
'NULL' as social,'NULL' as social_1,'NULL' as social_2,e.total
from eighth_to_ninth_marks as e 

union all

select t.admission_number ,t.student_class ,t.student_name,'NULL'as telugu, 
cast(t.telugu_1 as char(4)) as telungu_1,CAST(t.telugu_2 as CHAR(4)) as telugu_2,
t.hindi,'NULL' as english,CAST(t.english_1 as CHAR(4)) as english_1,
CAST(t.english_2 as CHAR(4)) as english_2,'NULL' as maths,CAST(t.maths_1 as CHAR(4)) as maths_1,
CAST(t.maths_2 as CHAR(4)) as maths2,'NULL' as science,CAST(t.ns as CHAR(4)) as ns,CAST(t.ps as CHAR(4))as ps,
'NULL' as social,CAST(t.social_1 as CHAR(4)) as social_1,CAST(t.social_2 as CHAR(4)) as social_2,t.total
from tenthclass_marks as t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return 'NULL' instead of 0 directly from your query. Beware that the returned value won't be a number after this change, so use this query ONLY for filling the grid:

```
SELECT l.admission_number,l.student_class,
    l.student_name, 
    CASE hindi WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), hindi), 
    CASE maths WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), maths), 
    CASE social WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), social),
    CASE l.telugu WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), l.telugu),
    CASE l.english WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), l.english),
    '' as english_1, '' as english_2,l.science, '' as ns,'' as ps 
FROM lkg_to_seventh_marks as l 
UNION ALL 
SELECT e.admission_number ,e.student_class , 
    e.student_name, 
    CASE hindi WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), hindi), 
    CASE maths WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), maths), 
    CASE social WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), social),
    CASE e.telugu WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), e.telugu),
    '' as english, 
    CASE e.english_1 WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), e.english_1),
    CASE e.english_2 WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), e.english_2),
    '' as science,
    CASE e.ns WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), e.ns),
    CASE e.ps WHEN 0 THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15), e.ps)
FROM eighth_to_ninth_marks as e
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: I want to say something like my table doesn't content 0 value..I get the 0 value after my query is executed and directly loaded t datagridview

Comment: OK. So you've hidden something from us :D

Comment: Where do those zeroes come from?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421788/how-to-write-a-query-of-3-tables-same-columns-and-among-them-one-different-colum) please have look into this question,from this question I get the query

Comment: The problem is not with the query. It was fine since the starting point. You are telling me that the zero values do not reside inside your table, so where do they come from? What is in the table that is shown a 0 in the grid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63768/discussion-between-shiva-debrown-and-alireza).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'd like to replace *every* instance of 0 with a string, one way to do this would be to use the DataGridView's RowsAdded event. Get a reference to the row through the DataGridViewRowEventArgs, iterate through each DataGridViewItem in the row, and change any 0 values you encounter to whatever you'd like to replace it with.

Here's an example usage of the event:

```
private void dataGridView1_NewRowNeeded(object sender,
        DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value == "0" || cell.Value == 0) // not sure which you're using
        {
             cell.Value = "your replacement value here";
        }
    }
}
```

MSDN has an article on RowsAdded here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Note that RadioSpace and AliReza are right - modifying elements in a UI control after you've already fed it your data is a little backwards and overcomplex.

Comment: do you have a code example to achieve this while data-binding ?

Comment: Adding one now. I'm assuming he's using WinForms, given that DataGridView doesn't exist in WPF. I don't think the fact that he's data-binding will matter - I used a similar fix with the DataGrid in WPF. He should still test it, though.

Comment: Yes I'm using Win forms

Comment: I would prefer the op to `filteredList = dataset.filter()` but I have been in situations where the Ideal is not going to happen, because you were told not to do it  that way. so an exercise in the wrong way rite. is always warrented +1

Comment: @ShivaDebrown Please try out the solution above and select the answer with the check mark if it works for you.

Comment: Can you give any more details? You can't just paste that code into your file and have it work automatically.